# how to get 2 different Models data in one Controller in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

using Larvel 9 and I have Employee and Title Models with relationship one to many. now I need call a function to get all employee and title data using EmployeeController as following.

```
 public function getEmployee() {
        return response()->json(Employee::all(), 200);
    }
}
```

my api route is this

```
Route::get('employees','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@getEmployee');
```

how could I get title data also in same EmployeeController in same getEmployee function?

Comment: Employee::with('title')->all() it should work

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze No, you can't chain `->all()` like that. It would be `->get()`. Either `Model::all()`, or `Model::with(...)->get()`.

Comment: The question isn't really clear, i try to put some hint maybe those are the answer, if not more details about what you want to obtain are appreciated.
Since you have the Employee model you should be able to retrieve his related title via $employee->title if the relation is defined in Employee model.
If you need Employees and related titles all extracted from a single query you can use the join() or the Has (whereHas etc.) functions on query builder to extract your dataset

Comment: @Simo I need get all employee data with related title data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Relationship setup between your `Employee` and `Title` Models, you can simply do:

```php
public function getEmployees() {
  return response()->json(['employees' => Employee::with('title')->get()], 200);
}
```

Also, in newer versions of Laravel, the syntax for Routes is as follows:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController;

Route::get('/employees', [EmployeeController::class, 'getEmployees'])->name('employees');
```

If you do not have a Relationship setup, or you want both Models separately, you can simply query both models:

```php
public function getEmployees() {
  return response()->json([
    'employees' => Employee::get(), // or `::all()`
    'titles' => Title::get()
  ], 200);
}
```

References:

- [Laravel Models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)
- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: thanks this is working fine. please one question how could I add another model like salary with Employee like title?

Comment: `Emlployee::with(['title', 'salary'])->get()`, assuming `Salary` is a Model and you have a Relationship, or `'salary' => Salary::get()`, etc.

Comment: All of this is in the Documentation I linked, please have a read through of it to understand these concepts 